# Apply filter on subform and open a report based on the filter

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a subform which allows user to select a value for "ACFTsn"  I would like to apply a filter to a table entitled "Logbook", where "sn"(field on the table) = ACFTsn
the following is attached to a button on the subform

```
Me.Form.Filter = "table![Logbook].SN=me.ACFTsn"
Me.FilterOn = True
DoCmd.openreport "logbook", acViewReport, Filter
```

When I step through the code, I receive error 3071/ expression typed incorrectly or too complex to be evaluated.

I am sure there are syntax errors, as this is my first attempt at a filter with VBA, and I'm not sure this is the correct way to apply it to the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be this simple:

```
Me.Filter = "[SN] = '" & Me!ACFTsn.Value & "'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

If SN is not a string:

```
Me.Filter = "[SN] = " & Me!ACFTsn.Value & ""
Me.FilterOn = True
```

To apply the same filter on the report:

```
DoCmd.openreport "logbook", acViewReport, , Me.Filter
```

Comment: I pasted the first two lines and followed them with:
DoCmd.openreport "Logbook", acViewReport  // the report opened, but was not filtered.

Comment: Then apply the filter to the report.

Comment: Works perfectly.  I missed the last line of your original post.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use the [ApplyFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197651.aspx) method or even [SetFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197950.aspx) (for MS Access 2010+):

```
Dim strfilter As String
strfilter = "[SN] = '" & Me!ACFTsn.Value & "'"

DoCmd.ApplyFilter , strfilter                          ' FILTERS FORM 
DoCmd.OpenReport "logbook", acViewReport, strfilter    ' FILTERS REPORT
```